# PowerShell cannot open shim file for read

Tags: powershell, scoop-installer

I have installed scoop in my Windows PowerShell for ability to install some apps.
When I install app and then try to run it I get an error that there is no possibility to find shim file.  `'C:\Windows\System32\apps\scoop\new'`  from my logs actually really doesn't exist. Maybe somebody had the same problem. I have found a clue that scoop could be out of date. I checked it and it really is but I cannot update it because i have still the same problem that it cannot read shim file.`'scoop config rm SCOOP_REPO'` also doesn't help. Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\apps\railway\current> scoop update
Updating Scoop...
Cannot open shim file for read.
Could not read shim file.
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\System32\apps\scoop\new' because it does not exist.
At C:\Windows\System32\apps\scoop\current\libexec\scoop-update.ps1:79 char:13
+             Remove-Item $newdir -Force -Recurse
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\System32\apps\scoop\new:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoun
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Scoop download failed. If this appears several times, try removing SCOOP_REPO by 'scoop config rm SCOOP_REPO'
```

Comment: Do you see file with File/Folder Explorer?  If you see the file then you do not have permission in powershell to see the file.  So most likely reason is that you are not an admin in powershell and are a admin using file explorer.  So start powershell by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Thanks but I run PowerShell as administrator and it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try file explorer?

Comment: Yes i have tried. `new` folder really doesn't exist. I have tried to add it manually but also without success.

Comment: Did you install scoop using an Admin account?  You just can't create the missing folder.  It must be installed properly.  A normal uses cannot write to the c:\Windows\System32 folder.  It must be done using an Admin Account.

Comment: Yes I have run PowerShell as admin. I failed traying to install scoop without this.

Comment: The error says the install failed : "Scoop download failed. If this appears several times, try removing SCOOP_REPO by 'scoop config rm SCOOP_REPO'"